# Redeploying web-app on tomcat container fails because of web.xml missing even though its present in the war

Tags: deployment, java-8, tomcat7, chef-infra

**Environment**
JDK 1.8
Tomcat 7.0.55
A spring web app
Chef scripts for deploying

**What's the issue**

The application is deployed via chef and most of the times everything is fine. Except for 1 in 10 times or so the web.xml (under appbase webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) goes missing during redeployment which causes the application not to start up.

This symptom disappears in eventual chef-runs adding to the peculiarity of the issue.

**My investigation till now**

1. Ruled out any chef aspects from the problem . Was able to confirm that the scripts are doing what they are suppose to do  - delete old war DIR -> unzip new war DIR in place(we use exploded war's) there by causing un-deploy of old and deployment of new.
2. Next point of investigation was to see if the tomcat is deploying the new web app even before its completely unzipped or extracted - this was not the case as confirmed by time lines on the logs.
3. We do not have jar's getting locked - so ruled out any issues caused by such scenarios.

   All of the symptoms I see now points towards tomcats auto deployment policies - but was not able to see anything [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html) which would cause such kind of inconsistency -  Have gone through tomcat bug list sniffing for any compatibility issues but was not able to find any.

Am putting it out there to see if any one else is facing similar issues - any thoughts are welcome. Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: The autodeploy feature of tomcat watch the directory periodically, and I would continue to dig on point 2. of your investigation. It's likely that tomcat start to deploy your app before the extraction end.

Comment: @Tensibai thank you for the insight. I have re-confirmed from the logs that the unzip has completed before tomcat picks up for auto deployment . During the auto deployment of tomcat our scripts are still in process of changing some file permissions(chmod) on files with in the unzipped war - would you think this can affect the auto deployment process ?

Comment: if it helps we reduce the permissions because of [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#Non-Tomcat_settings)

Comment: Indeed it can affect it, if you end up changing perm (and thus locking the file) while tomcat try to read it, you probably end up with a missing file (I **GUESS** that as the file system is currently modifying the perm it can't tell if the access should be allowed or not, and act as if the file is absent). Workaround: stage your deployment, once all is done (unzip, template deploying within, perm change), hardlink in place, it takes near no time, and all is accessible to tomcat at the same time.